# What's the standard way to emplace a map?

Tags: c++, c++11

The standard seems to be a bit [broken](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2006) on this, so as far as I've found it only leaves us with this "correct" way of emplacing a map with non-unary constructors of `Type` ([from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)):

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
// uses pair's piecewise constructor (overload 6)
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple("c"),
          std::forward_as_tuple(10, 'c'));
```

Since this is butt-ugly, I was wondering if there is a standard, nice way of emplacing map elements that won't require the copy constructor of `Type` to be called. Current I'm doing this:

```
m.emplace("c",std::string(10, 'c'));
```

But that doesn't feel particularly *emplacy*. Is there a better way?

Comment: It might be useful to show the definition of `m`. In particular, is the Key `std:string`  ? Sounds logical, more than `const char*`, but we're currently guessing.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's a great idea for the Standard to provide support for `emplace` that assumes there'll be one constructor argument for the key and the rest for the value (as mentioned in the "bit broken" link, but if that's what you want then you could easily code up a non-member `emplace` function to do it ala `emplace(m, "c", 10, 'c');` that uses the verbose but conceptually robust `piecewise_construct` internally.

Comment: @MSalters well in my case `Type` is a (potentially large) class that may or may not support a move constructor.. As for the example, it's `std::string` (I added it to the code).

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz: Still unclear on the relation between `Type` and `std::map`. The canonical templaet params are `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: @MSalters, sorry, I got confobulated. I meant `Value` not `Type`. The `Key` is a primitive or simple user-defined class and the `Value` is a larger object.

Answer (score 1):

The `emplace` parameters in `std::map<K,T>` are forwarded to a `std::pair<const K, V>` constructor. It means that you are restricted to available [ones](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

As you will see, there is not much you can do to improve the syntax, the only variadic construct is the one you use in your first code snippet. All others require an already complete `K` and `V`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with `m.emplace("c",std::string(10, 'c'));`? `std::map` needs to store a `std::pair` to hold key and value. The call `m.emplace(A,B)` looks perfectly reasonable to specify both key (1. argument) and value (2. argument).

It becomes tricky when the construction of key and/or value requires not only one, but several arguments. Then you have to use the piecewise constructor as mentioned in your question. It is  in general impossible to use a variadic template function to construct *two* objects.

Comment: Well it looks like it would invoke `std::string`'s copy constructor, which would be nice to avoid since it's unnecessary (in this case it's probably a trivial performance difference, but perhaps not in other applications).

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz `std::string`'s **move** constructor, to be precise.

Comment: "It is actually in general impossible to use a variadic template function to construct two objects." - why?  Conceptually, you just need a dedicated sentinel type to separate the arguments for the key from those for the value; add a bucket-full of metaprogramming around it all.

Comment: @TonyD: And how should that work if you have constructors `Key(int)`, `Key(int,int)`, `Value(int)` and `Value(int,int)` and call `emplace(int,int,int)`?

Comment: @Danvil: as I said, you'd have to use a sentinel type... `emplace(int, Separator, int, int)` or `emplace(int, int, Separator, int)`.

Comment: @TonyD: Also, in general you can have maps of maps of ... Sentinels don't cut it if you have multiple levels. In that case, you need nesting. Which is pretty much what `()` does in `m.emplace("c",std::string(10, 'c'));`

Comment: @TonyD: Than I do not see the point of you comment. In my answer I stated "you have to use the piecewise constructor" - which uses a "sentinel".

Comment: @Danvil: I said above "a dedicated sentinel type to separate the arguments for the key from those for the value"... that "piecemeal" makes unrelated use of what is also a sentinel is unrelated.  MSalters is correct that a sentinel between key and value constructor arguments could only support one layer of constructor arguments, but that's still potentially useful, although `emplace(m, "c", sentinel(), 10, 'c')` would handle the case he talks about - it's levels beyond that that are problematic.